# The order of the Galois group of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory

So according to the book (Contemporary abstract algebra by Joseph Gallian), the order of the Galois group of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$ over $\mathbb Q$ is just $1,$ but the fundamental theorem of Galois theory says that this number should be equal to $[\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2}):\mathbb Q]$, which is 3, is there something I'm missing?

Comment: There is no Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ because the field extension is not Galois. There is only the group of automorphisms. There is only 1 automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ since $\sqrt[3]{2}$ can only be sent to itself.

Comment: I'm taking my second course on abstract algebra, so I don't know what it means that the extension is not Galois, could you elaborate?

Comment: If you know the fundamental theorem of Galois groups, you should know it doesn't apply to all field extensions. Specifically, your field does not "split" the polynomial $x^3-2,$ so the fundamental theorem does not apply.

Comment: According to the book, the extension need only be of characteristic 0 or finite, also a descomposition field, which I believe $Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$ over Q is

Comment: Look up "decomposition field" again. That's a term I don't know, but I'd guess it does not mean what you think it means.

Comment: The extension field $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)$ contains $\sqrt[3]2$. The minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[3]2$ over $\Bbb Q$ is $x^3-2$. The other roots of $x^3-2$ are not in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)$. This makes $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)$ not a normal extension of $\Bbb Q$, and normal is one of the two requirements that make up a Galois extension.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by characteristic. Under the definition I'm used to, all fields are characteristic $0$ or finite. Is this a case where you are translating to English?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews you're absolutely right, the only way for it to be a splitting field is if the extention contains all the zeros of the polynomial. Which $Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$ does not, thank you.

Comment: @JocsanArielHernandezBarahon The fundamental theorem of Galois theory only applies to field extensions $F/E$ which are Galois, so it seems bizarre that you would have learned this theorem but not learned what it means for an extension to be Galois. In general, a Galois extension $F / E$ is one where (1) every $f \in F$ is algebraic over $E$, and (2) if an irreducible polynomial $Q \in E[X]$ has a root in $F$, then it splits completely over $F$ and has distinct roots.

Comment: Technically, it needs a root in $F\setminus E$ to ensure it splits. @MarkSaving

Comment: @ThomasAndrews If $Q$ has a root in $e \in E$, then $X - e$ is a factor of $Q$ by the factor theorem. Since $Q$ is irreducible, it must therefore be linear, so it splits completely. So it's not necessary to specify that it has a root in $F \setminus E$.

Comment: Instead of a decomposition field you need a splitting field. This may be something lost in translation.

Comment: @MarkSaving Some authors (like Jacobson) denote the group of $K$-automorphisms of an extension field $L$ by $Gal(L/K)$ even when the extension is not Galois (possibly only when the extension is algebraic). So it is a stretch to say that *there is no Galois group*. Admittedly it is becoming less common (judging from what I have seen on this site). It is always a bit dangerous to try and pontificate (that applies to yours truly as well).

Comment: @MarkSaving: Unfortunately, some authors use "Galois group" to refer to the automorphism group, whether or not the extension is Galois. For example, Hungerford calls it "the Galois group of the extension" in all cases. I seem to recall an author that always called it the Galois group, and used $\mathrm{Aut}_K(F)$ when it was an arbitrary extension and $\mathrm{Gal}(F/K)$ when it was a Galois extension (but I can't seem to locate it right now). (To further complicate, yet *other* authors use "Galois group" to refer to the automorphism group of the Galois closure...)

Comment: Anyway, the fundamental theorem of Galois theory only applies to Galois extensions.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Maybe I've misunderstood your comment, but I'm not sure what you mean! Characteristic is a standard term. The point is that characteristic $0$ fields and finite fields are all perfect: every finite extension is separable. There are *plenty* of infinite fields that don't have characteristic zero (e.g. $\mathbb F_p(t)$).

Comment: @Mathmo123 The usual meaning of “characteristic” of a field is the number of times you have to add $1$ to itself to get $0.$ Or zero if there is no such number. Not sure where your definition of characteristic comes from, but it is certainly not the first meaning of the term that comes to my mind. The characteristic of a field, with this definition, is always prime or $0.$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_(algebra)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I think perhaps you misinterpreted the OP, and I in turn misinterpreted you. The OP wanted to restrict to characteristic $0$ fields and to finite fields, because they are perfect. I interpreted your statement "all fields are characteristic 0 or finite" to mean that every field is either characteristic $0$ or a finite field, which is of course false, but closely matches what the OP said: "the extension need only be of characteristic 0 or finite". I guess what you meant is that the characteristic of a field is either $0$ or finite?

Comment: @mathmo123 OP didn’t say “finite field.” OP said the characteristic of the extension must be $0$ or prime. The characteristic of a field extension is always the same as the original field, and is always $0$ or prime. Perhaps that is what OP meant, but that is not what OP said, so I guessed that OP was probably using another term, perhaps translating something from a non-English book, meaning something other than the usual definition of “characteristic.”